# description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, jsp

When I Start my maven(+ Spring) web project I have it
I don't know how fix it.

```
    HTTP Status 500 - 


type Exception report

message 

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet DispatcherServlet threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)



root cause 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/DispatcherServlet-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/DispatcherServlet-servlet.xml]
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:510)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)



root cause 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/DispatcherServlet-servlet.xml]
    org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:510)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.29 logs.

my pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.gemicle</groupId>
    <artifactId>webtimetable</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <finalName>root</finalName>
        <plugins>
<!--          <plugin> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>2.9</version> -->
<!--            <configuration> -->
<!--                    Always download and attach dependencies source code -->
<!--                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources> -->
<!--                <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs> -->
<!--                Avoid type mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0 -->
<!--                <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion> -->
<!--            </configuration> -->
<!--          </plugin> -->

<!--          Set JDK Compiler Level -->
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> 
        <version>3.5.1</version> 
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.3.7.v20160115</version>
                <configuration>
                    <war>${basedir}/webtimetable/root.war</war>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <!-- <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source> -->
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
         <!-- add new -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSON -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.json</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>json</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>20151123</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->

        <!-- Validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
            <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Titles -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>com.paypal.sdk</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>paypal-core</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>1.4.3</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>2.1</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

My Servlet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.gemicle.webtimetable" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <!-- <welcome-file-list> -->
    <!-- <welcome-file>welcome.jsp</welcome-file> -->
    <!-- </welcome-file-list> -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <!-- <init-param> -->
        <!-- <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> -->
        <!-- <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/webcontext/DispatcherServlet-context.xml</param-value> -->
        <!-- </init-param> -->
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/webcontext/DispatcherServlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

WEB-INF

-----spring

-----------webcontext

---------------------DispetcherServlet xml

-----web.xml

-----views

---------- here jsp files

and me controller is

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String welcome(ModelMap model) {

        model.addAttribute("greeting", "Welcome to Web Store!");
        model.addAttribute("tagline", "The one and only amazing webstore");
        return "welcome";
    }
```

jsp welcome file

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<title>title</title>
</head>
<body>

    <section>
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>${greeting}</h1>
                <p>${tagline}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

With Spring Web MVC there are two application contexts that are created. The first one is a root application context that should contain your business logic i.e service daos etc. This application context is created by the ContextLoaderListener. By default the file name should be /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml. You can customise this by specifying a contextConfigLocation context-param as you did.

The second is the dispatcher application context containing your web specific beans e.g controllers. BY default its location is /WEB-INF/[servle-name]-servlet.xml where [servlet-name] is the name of your DispatcherServlet in web.xml. You can customise this as well using init-param contextConfigLocation (the part you commented out in your web.xml)

In your case you do not have a root application context so you can remove the ContextLoaderListener and its context param. Alternatively create a root application context even if it can be empty (mostly likely you will need to add aditional beans here)

Then uncomment the init-param for DispatcherServlet to use your Dispatcher-context.xml instead of the default Dispatcher-servlet.xml

Solution 1

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <!-- <welcome-file-list> -->
    <!-- <welcome-file>welcome.jsp</welcome-file> -->
    <!-- </welcome-file-list> -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> -->
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/webcontext/DispatcherServlet-context.xml</param-value> 
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Solution 2

Create file /WEB-INF/spring/webcontext/Application-context.xml (it can be empty)

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <!-- <welcome-file-list> -->
    <!-- <welcome-file>welcome.jsp</welcome-file> -->
    <!-- </welcome-file-list> -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/webcontext/DispatcherServlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>     </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/webcontext/Application-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```